# How to abbreviate "\begin{frame}", "\end{frame}", and "\frametitle"?

Tags: beamer, framed, frame-title

Aware abbreviating those commands need not always be helpful, I would like to know how to abbreviate them? The following is what I tried, which does not work:

```
\documentclass[11pt,handout]{beamer}
\newcommand{\bframe}{\begin{frame}}
\newcommand{\eframe}{\end{frame}}
\newcommand{\ftitle}{\frametitle}


\author{Author}
\title{Title}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

\end{frame}


\bframe
\ftitle{Introduction}

\eframe



\end{document}
```

At first I thought it might be the case that commands such as `\bframe` was already defined. But using `\def` instead still gives no desired result.

Comment: Quick advise: Just don't do it ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know, and I can comment them off, right?

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to abbreviate latex environment syntax, sometimes it works but for many enviroments (frame, ams align, verbatim, etc) it does not work, and even when it works for latex it usually confuses syntax highlighting etc. Environments are the main syntactic structure of the latex language, they shouldn't be hidden, they should be used.

Comment: Okay, thank you for cautioning. I would like to know in theory how to do it.Possible or not?

Comment: I am afraid I am not asking "Is it wise to abbreviate so and so?" :)

Comment: Isn't the official `\begin{frame}{My frame title}...\end{frame}` short enough?

Comment: @AlexG, I write those statements so often I want it shorter. Going back and forth to copy is irritating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain a result similar to `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` by

```
\def\bframe#1\eframe{\begin{frame}#1\end{frame}}
```

but I can't see any improvement both in typing speed and in clarity of the typescript.

With the above definition you can do

```
\bframe
<contents>
\eframe
```

but don't even try adding arguments such as `[fragile]` because it won't definitely work.

There is no problem into doing

```
\newcommand{\ftitle}{\frametitle}
```

but, again, I see no advantage in typing

```
\ftitle{Gnus and gnats}
```

instead of

```
\frametitle{Gnus and gnats}
```

Answer (score 2):

For lazy writers, already there is a shortcut:

```
\frame{{<frametitle>}<contents>}
```

MME:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{{Hello} Hello,Moon}
\end{document}
```

However, if you need frame arguments ...

Comment: This is old syntax supported for historical reasons: please avoid in new code.

Comment: And though your time is appreciated, I would say it is about efficiency rather than laziness. But, yes, there may exist somebody who would like to write 3.14159... instead of $\pi$.

Comment: @JosephWright,  I have no doubt you're right.  For me is enough bad that   `[fragile]` does not work ... but  using `\frame` is discouraged somewhere in the manual? Why you keep around 50 examples using `\frame`?

Comment: @Chou Surely you search for shorcuts for efficiency in mind, but in my case is only lazyness `;)`