# How to use `\end{frame}` in a command?

Tags: beamer, macros

I would like to create a command that ends a beamer frame. However, this leads to the error message quoted below - probably due to the same problem that prevents indentation of frame commands, cf. [Indenting \end{frame} in fragile slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234778/indenting-endframe-in-fragile-slides/234789#234789).

The error message is: `! File ended while scanning use of \next.`

Below is a failing MWE that can be made working by commenting out `\end{frame}` in the definition of `\pfooter` plus uncommenting it at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[english,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\pheader}[1]{%
    \section{bla: blabla}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]{blabla}
}

\newcommand{\pfooter}{\end{frame}
    % some other commands
}

\begin{document}
\pheader{}
  \begin{lstlisting}[gobble=4]
    1234567890
  \end{lstlisting}

  bla
\pfooter{}
% \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically you can't. And even if it was possible, why?

Comment: Frames are special environments, that explicitly check for `\end{frame}`. There are ways around, most of the time they cause more problems than they solve, so please don't do this.

Comment: Some inspiring quote related to this idea: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253892/how-to-abbreviate-beginframe-endframe-and-frametitle#comment606776_253892